# How to rotate an icon in both directions in two clicks?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to rotate an icon 90 degree clock wise direction on first click and 90 degree anticlockwise on second click. (remember that the icon can load using either `<i>` tag or `<span>` tag )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="#"><div class="fa fa-anchor  rotation_90deg"></div></a>
```

Add to css classes like below

```
.rotation_90deg{
   -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
   -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
   transition: all 2s linear;
}

.rotation_90deg.down{
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
   transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

And in your script

```
$(".rotation_90deg").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("down")  ; 
});
```

working fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/zakirshakir/3v2egwfs/790/